# Fatal error: Call to a member function post() on a non-object

Tags: php, html

> Update: $thiss was a typo. Changed it to $this

I have a problem with my code. I'm getting this error

`Fatal error: Call to a member function post() on a non-object`

This code is for uploading an image to a directory in the server. and eventually read the images to a gallery (Which I am still going to make.) How to solve the fatal error? The error is on the  `$photo = $this->input->post($_FILES['image']);` with the `$this`.

here is the code.

```
<?php
// If Everything is good- process the form - write the data into the database

$photo = $this->input->post($_FILES['image']);

if($photo==NULL){$image_name='0';}// if no photo is selected the default value of the photo would be 0

//photo upload starts
    $errors=0;
    if($_FILES['image'])
    {
        $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        if($image) 
        {
            define ("MAX_SIZE","100"); 
            function getExtension($str) 
            {   
                 $i = strrpos($str,".");
                if (!$i) { return ""; }
                $l = strlen($str) - $i;
            $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext; 
    }


    //reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];                                   
    //if it is not empty
    if ($image) 
    {                               

    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

            //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
                  $extension = getExtension($filename);
                  $extension = strtolower($extension);

                   //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not  upload the file,  
                            //otherwise we will do more tests
                            if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
                            {           
                                //print error message
                                $msg="Sorry! Unknown extension. Please JPG,JPEG,PNG and GIF only ";
                                $errors=1;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //get the size of the image in bytes
                                //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
                                //in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
                                $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);                              
                                //compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
                            if ($size < MAX_SIZE*1024)
                            {

                                //we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
                                $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
                                //the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)                                                        
                                $newname="uploads/".$image_name;                                                     
                                //we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead                                                     
                                $copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);        

                            if (!$copied)                                                       
                            {                                                       
                                $msg="Sorry, The Photo Upload was unsuccessfull!";                                                          
                                $errors=1;                                                          
                                 }                                                         
                            }                                               
                            else                                            
                            {       
                                    $msg="You Have Exceeded The Photo Size Limit";          
                                    $errors=1;                              
                            }

                         }
                    }
                }                                             

                            /*Image upload process ends here- If any problem occurs it will display error message via the $msg, 
                             otherwise it will upload the image to the image folder. To insert the photo into database $image_name has been used*/ 

                }


                if(($_FILES['image'])&& ($errors))/* If any photo is selected and any problem occurs while uploading it will
                                                            display an error message, otherwise transfer the data to Mod_addstudent model  */
                                    { 

                            echo $msg;


                                    }

                else        {   

                                //Insert into database.Just use this particular variable "$image_name" when you are inserting into database

                                    $sql="INSERT INTO your_table (field1, your_image_field) VALUES ('','$image_name')"; 




                            }
            ?>
```

Comment: $thiss->input->post or $this->input->post ?

Comment: Is this a typo?  `$thiss->input->post($_FILES['image']);`

Comment: @AudunLarsen yes.. that one.. the  $photo = $thiss->input->post($_FILES['image']);
 never mind the $_FILES['image']); thought it might work actually but didn't. :(

Comment: @DamienPirsy no, Im afraid not. I tried that thought might work but didn't. :(

Comment: actually if I try this  
    $photo = $this->input->post('image');

another error comes saying Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

so i changed it to another word as adviced from here.. but didn't work still

Comment: @SimonCode Where is "input" defined? Looks like a call to a class that calls another class' method

Comment: @DamienPirsy actually I didnt get that part there too.. it was a code given to me and I am also analyzing this code.. sorry im not that good in php yet.. :(

Comment: Yeah, but as you see "$this->input->post('')" calls the method input inside a class which itself returns an object on which you access the method "post". I saw something like this in frameworks (Codeigniter, for.ex. has the same identical call). Are you sure your code is for PHP alone and not part of a framework? are you instantiating all the needed classes?

Answer (score 2):

If this is how your start your page:

```
<?php
// If Everything is good- process the form - write the data into the database

$photo = $this->input->post($_FILES['image']);
```

Then you are not inside a class and therefore "$this" is not an object like it would be if you were inside a class.